# How would the chain of command work if a service member were elected president?

Tags: united-states, president, military

[Tulsi Gabbard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulsi_Gabbard) is currently enlisted in the Hawaii Army National Guard and running for president. If elected, she would become commander-in-chief, as opposed to Major (O-4), her current rank. Would she have to be formally discharged from the military? If not, how would that chain of command be managed?

Answer (score 1):

It's a well established constitutional principle that the commander in chief is a civilian, so yes, she would have to resign.  I could not find a statute or regulation stating this explicitly, however.

Comment: As an off-topic curiosity, in my country Finland, when elected president, traditionally, once elected, he/she even cancels his/her party membership. This is symbolic, but I think good symbolic meaning. Still, typically if/when running for their 2nd terms, they tend to run representing their former parties. [Our current one, a guy with a cute dog, see link at the end, now on  his 2nd term, made an exception and successfully ran as an independent candidate for his 2nd term] https://www.huffpost.com/entry/twitter-is-obsessed-with-the-president-of-finlands-dog-lennu_n_58ae8863e4b05ca474a0b8d7